# Sitecore 8 search against index for pages giving a specific tag

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm working on upgrading from 8.1 to 8.2 update 3. I understand that the search/indexing was changed and some code is obsolete or no longer works.

Unfortunately in one of our class projects there were some methods our sitecore partners had built for us that are no longer working due to obsolete code and now I need help updating that code. I've been able to narrow it down to just 2 files, with some simple code.

Here is the first set of code:

```
public partial class TagResults
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Searches against the Lucene index for pages given a specific tag
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<BasePage> GetPagesForTag(string Tag, int page, int pageSize, out int totalCount)
    {
        var tags = new List<BasePage>();

        Index searchIndex = SearchManager.GetIndex(Constants.LuceneIndexes.Tags);
        using (IndexSearchContext context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
        {
            //The wildcard search allows us to pull back all items with the given tag
            var query = new WildcardQuery(new Term(Constants.LuceneFields.Tags, Tag));
            SearchHits hits = context.Search(query);

            totalCount = hits.Length;

            //Go through the results 
            SearchResultCollection results = hits.FetchResults(page * pageSize, pageSize);
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                var searchItem = result.GetObject<Item>();
                Item currentDbItem = ItemUtility.GetItem(searchItem.ID);
                //Store the item if it exists and is a descendant of the news listing
                if (currentDbItem != null)
                {
                    tags.Add(new BasePage(currentDbItem));
                }
            }
        }

        return tags.ToList();
    }

    public static bool IsItemCastable(Item sitecoreItem)
    {
        return sitecoreItem != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sitecoreItem[FieldIds.IsTagResultsComponent]);
    }
}
```

I think I have some of this changed correctly:

```
ISearchIndex searchIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(Constants.LuceneIndexes.tags);
using (IProviderSearchContext context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContent())
```

But then I get stuck on

```
SearchHits hits = context.Search(query);

            totalCount = hits.Length;

            //Go through the results 
            SearchResultCollection results = hits.FetchResults(page * pageSize, pageSize);
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
```

Now I'm asking a lot but I am learning. If someone could help me correct this, I would be really appreciative. I've been doing a lot of searching to try to figure out how to correct this but I feel like I'm missing something and I just need some help.

Thank you in advance.